# What does "Marking not allowed" mean in the context of unattended upgrades / apt?

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

Got this line of output when running `sudo unattended-upgrade -d --dry-run`. Not sure what to make of it.

Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrors.digitalocean.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en'  a=jammy-updates,c=main,v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,l=Ubuntu arch='' site='mirrors.digitalocean.com' IndexType='Debian Translation Index' Size=1160234 ID:9> with -327XX pin